# I can't remove the ring around the focused window in ubuntu 23.10

Tags: gnome, 23.10

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 23.04 to 23.10 and now the focused window has as a blue ring around it.

[image]

I want to remove it.
I have tried the following without success:

- Restarting the computer
- Disabled all gnome extensions and restarting the computer
- Changed the window theme
- sudo apt autoremove

The color of the ring does not change if I change the accent color on the settings.

How can I disable this ring?

Answer (score 1):

The style_class name for the ring is `cycler-highlight`.

You may override this by using custom theme or otherways.

I have installed user-themes extension.
Created a folder named `custom` in `.themes` directory.
created a folder `gnome-shell`
created a file `gnome-shell.css`

`/home/<username>/.themes/custom/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css`

contents of `gnome-shell.css` to override the styling is

```
.cycler-highlight {
  border: 5px solid yellow; // make it(5px solid yellow) to none for your case
}
```

once saved. Choose the `custom` theme from `user-themes` extension.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering. 

I have followed your instructions, but doesn't seem to have any effect on my machine. I also tried rebooting.

Comment: Hi, Oh sorry to hear that. May be after some update, that might work. Since it did not work you can remove this custom theme.

Answer (score 0):

I was tinkering with the definitions of the extension "Ubuntu Tiling Assistant" and I found the solution! Changing the option "Active Window Hint" from Always to Disabled does it.